# After upgrade TYPO3 6.2 to TYPO3 7.6 'page Layout' not display in Backend

Tags: typo3

[image]

Versions:

```
TYPO3 :-  7.6.18
Flux:  7.4.0
Vhs: - 3.0.1
Fluidpages: 3.6.0
Fluidcontent: 4.4.1
```

I already modified in typoscript also select 'fluidpage' from 'Appearance' BE Tab.

```
    5 >
    5 = USER
    5.userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    5.extensionName = Fluidpages
    5.vendorName = FluidTYPO3
    5.pluginName = Page
    10 >
```

[image]

But still not showing ‘page layout’ in backend.

Comment: Did you already set up some page templates (with the flux syntax for backend)?

Comment: yes i already added template.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you registered the extension that hld your page templates as a provider in the extensions `ext_localconf.php`:

```
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('Vendor.MyExt', 'Page');
```

Then put your page templates under `Resources/Private/Templates/Page` and you should be fine. Your templates need at least a configuration and a content section:

```
<f:layout name="Page/Default" />
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="MyPage" />
    <flux:form.option name="icon" value="EXT:my_ext/Resources/Public/Icons/PageIcon.jpg" />
    // Additional configuration
</f:section>

<f:section name="Content">
    //render the content
</f:section>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It's working. I forgot ext_localconf.php